# Flair seems to be broken

Tags: bug, flair, 500-server-error

Under **Edit profile and settings > Flair**, for all 4 themes (Default, Clean, Dark, Hotdog) images are not displayed.

The console is showing an error as:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

[image: Broken Flair]